# a repeated permutation with limitations

Tags: arrays, ruby, permutation

I am trying to generate all possible combinations of certain values in an array of 15 which add up to 50.

```
$a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
print $a.repeated_permutation(15).to_a
```

In this case,

```
[2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3]
[2,2,2,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3]
[2,2,4,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3]
```

are all possible answers.

After some investigation I realize the code to do this is a bit over my head, but I will leave the question up if it might help someone else.

For some reference as to what I am working on, Project Euler, problem 114. It's pretty difficult, and so I am attempting to solve only a single case where my 50-space-long grid is filled only with 3-unit-long blocks. The blocks must be separated by at least one blank, so I am counting the blocks as 4. This (with some tweaking, which I have left out as this is confusing enough already) allows for twelve blocks plus three single blanks, or a maximum of fifteen elements.

Comment: Did you add Ruby code to C?:)

Comment: if you can't implement repeated_permutation in Ruby by yourself, [check this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161627/understanding-the-source-code-for-rubys-repeated-permutation-method) and add correctives you need.

Comment: Your example is bad. Even if you pick all elements, they add up to only 13.3. There is no combination that satisfies the condition.

Comment: probably true that's not a repeated permutation

Comment: Thanks Rustam, I am pretty sure this is too hard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach**

I think recursion is the way to go here, where your recursive method looks like this:

```
def recurse(n,t)
```

where

- `n` is the number of elements required; and
- `t` is the required total.

If we let `@arr` be the array of integers you are given, `recurse(n,t)` returns an array of all permutations of `n` elements from `@arr` that sum to `t`.

**Assumption**

I have assumed that the elements of `@arr` are non-negative integers, sorted by size, but the method can be easily modified if it includes negative integers (though performance will suffer). Without loss of generality, we can assume the elements of `@arr` are unique, sorted by increasing magnitude.

**Code**

```
def recurse(n,t)
  if n == 1
    @arr.include?(t) ? [[t]] : nil
  else
    @arr.each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
      break if i > t # as elements of @arr are non-decreasing
      if (ret = recurse(n-1,t-i))
        ret.each { |b| a << [i,*b] }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
@arr = [3, 4, 1, 2, 5].sort
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

recurse(1,4)
  #=> [[4]]
recurse(2,6)
  #=> [[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1]] 
recurse(3,10)
  #=> [[1, 4, 5], [1, 5, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 4], [2, 5, 3],
  #    [3, 2, 5], [3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 3], [3, 5, 2], [4, 1, 5],
  #    [4, 2, 4], [4, 3, 3], [4, 4, 2], [4, 5, 1], [5, 1, 4],
  #    [5, 2, 3], [5, 3, 2], [5, 4, 1]] 
recurse(3,50)
  #=> []
```

**Improvement**

We can do better, however, by first computing all combinations, and then computing the permutations of each of those combinations.

```
def combo_recurse(n,t,last=0)
    ndx = @arr.index { |i| i >= last }
    return nil if ndx.nil?
    arr_above = @arr[ndx..-1] 
  if n == 1
    arr_above.include?(t) ? [[t]] : nil
  else
    arr_above.each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
      break if i > t # as elements of @arr are non-decreasing
      if (ret = combo_recurse(n-1,t-i,i))
        ret.each { |b| a << [i,*b] }
      end
    end
  end
end

combo_recurse(1,4)
  #=> [[4]]
combo_recurse(2,6)
  #=> [[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3]] 
combo_recurse(3,10)
  #=> [[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4]] 
combo_recurse(3,50)
  #=> [] 
combo_recurse(15,50).size
  #=> 132 
combo_recurse(15,50).first(5)
  #=> [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

We can then compute the permutations from the combinations:

```
combo_recurse(2,6).flat_map { |a| a.permutation(a.size).to_a }.uniq
  #=> [[1, 5], [5, 1], [2, 4], [4, 2], [3, 3]] 
combo_recurse(3,10).flat_map { |a| a.permutation(a.size).to_a }.uniq
  #=> [[1, 4, 5], [1, 5, 4], [4, 1, 5], [4, 5, 1], [5, 1, 4],
  #    [5, 4, 1], [2, 3, 5], [2, 5, 3], [3, 2, 5], [3, 5, 2],
  #    [5, 2, 3], [5, 3, 2], [2, 4, 4], [4, 2, 4], [4, 4, 2],
  #    [3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 3], [4, 3, 3]]
```

We can approximate the number of permutations for `(15,50)` (it will be somewhat high because `uniq` is not applied):

```
def factorial(n)
  (1..n).reduce :*
end

Math.log10 combo_recurse(15,50).reduce(1) { |t,a| t*factorial(a.size) }
  #=> 1599.3779486682888
```

That is, the result has about 1,600 digits. What platform will you be running this on?

Comment: Win 7 x64... Hmm. Maybe I have met yet another Euler problem where my chance to hit is 0%.

Comment: @Will, I don't understand your reference to the [Brenneke cartridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7%C3%9764mm).